# Am I improving my questions and are self-answers useful?

Tags: discussion, asking-questions, post-ban, self-answer, quality-improvement

Unfortunately, for the 3rd time in a row I have been question banned. This time I'm really taking it seriously. I have been going through all of my questions to try to improve them, answering other questions to try to create a positive impact, and even answering my own questions that I just undeleted.

My question is, am I doing everything right? Also, is there anything wrong with my questions that I need to be more careful about in the future? Since I'm a computer science student, there is a lot I don't know, and oftentimes I don't even know the correct term, thus prompting me to ask an (admittedly somewhat useless) question.

Additionally, I am not sure whether my self-answers are beneficial or whether I'm depriving another user from writing their own great answer. Do they even help my question record, due to most of my questions now having an accepted answer?

Below are two examples of useless questions that I just undeleted in an attempt to improve them.

[Question 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63802512/problem-running-java-code-in-visual-studio-code-problem-solved)

[Question 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65096911/how-to-create-a-storage-folder-for-java-files)

Edit: Ironically this Meta question has drawn more attention to my questions which resulted in my getting un-question banned again. Anyway my question still stands because I need to make sure to avoid a 4th question ban in a row.

Edit 2: I have figured out my mistake. In the short time that I undeleted one of my questions, it has gained 15 views and now has over 100. So I think what happened is I deleted a useful question, which Stack Overflow marked negatively. I think in the future I have to avoid deleting questions at all costs.

Comment: Your second question is just *factually* incorrect.  You don't use packages to organize a dozen different projects.  One might do that if they didn't know how to organize Java projects, which is...what you're asking.

Comment: @Makoto Well, the purpose of that question is finding out how you DO organize Java projects. Basically asking, "If I can't use packages, what CAN I use?" Also, I ended up finding a way to do it, which proves it wasn't entirely a failure.

Comment: How did you get out of the ban the two previous times?

Comment: @RobertLongson Probably from posting good answers.

Comment: Posting good answers has a very small effect on question bans as far as we can tell.

Comment: @RobertLongson Well, I posted a lot of them. More than 20 with 1+ upvotes I think.

Comment: You'll need to forgive the analogy, but suggesting that finding a way to do something means it isn't a failure is equivalent to watching a 2 year old eat ice cream by licking their feet.  Sure, it works - for a given definition of "works" - but is still *incorrect*.

Comment: @Makoto Yeah, I know, I know, my question sucks, but the problem is that deleting it won't help me. So I have to find some way to try to salvage it.

Comment: it's also not exactly a ban, more of a throttle. The worst it can get is one question every 6 months, but it does slow you down prior to reaching that point too. As far as your questions are concerned, I'd be very careful not to ask questions about a language or platform I haven't used/learned yet without first doing extensive research. The easiest way to receive a quick downvote is to ask a question that can be answered with a quick glance at the docs. Unfotunately... once asked, such questions aren't really fixable. An edit may improve it, but it won't make it not what it is.

Comment: "Since I'm a computer science student, [...]", you might have a "wrong mentality" here. I haven't checked any of your questions: SO is not a replacement for your studies. When you don't know something, ask your teachers. If that's not possible somehow, ask other students. If that's not possible, then do *extensive* research, not just a bit googling for 10 minutes. And then, when you are still struggeling, it's the time to post on SO. You need to be aware of the "danger" when posting trivial questions, or questions that are posted without previous research.

Comment: @M-Chen-3 - You could easily improve that second question.  You could provide the code as text.  You can provide the error as text.  You can remove the screenshot after you do both of those things.  Those are just two minor improvements that would more than likely stop the downvotes on that second question.  Since you submitted the question and received an answer it's too late to delete the question.  However, ALL questions you submit, are counted towards you.  You should work on getting any of your deleted questions restored and improve those.

Comment: @SecurityHound Well the reason I provided the screenshot is so you can see how my folders are organized. I already provide the error as text. Also, the code isn't relevant since my question doesn't concern coding.

Comment: @M-Chen-3 - You indicated you were looking for ways to salvage it.

Comment: @SecurityHound I don't really agree with the changes, but I implemented them anyways since you know more than I do. I hope they'll help.

Comment: @M-Chen-3 - You could have also kept the screenshot but also provided the code and error.

Comment: @Makoto I’m not sure if I can forgive that analogy. :-) Do you have a photo? How does licking your feet even manage to accomplish the task of eating ice cream? Do you… just let the ice cream melt and drip onto your feet, then lick it off? Arguably then, you are not eating ice cream, but melted cream.

Comment: @CodyGray https://twitter.com/DudeWhoCode/status/1327416318308466688 - remember: it's a toddler who doesn't know better. You don't fault the kid for doing it, but you have to impart to them that this is not how you do this.

Comment: Well, that's significantly more usable than the software *I've* been involved with that avoided spending any time on UX. I mean, at least the user figured out a way to actually use it. Anyway, the picture definitely helps. Might want to include that link with future references to that analogy.

Comment: @Makoto, I'm ROFL that you actually had that video waiting in the wings.  I'm sure Cody didn't expect that response when he asked if you had a photo.  Classic!  You've made my weekend for sure.  I LOVE IT!